# Open ActionBarActivity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a novice question. How can I open an ActionBarActivity that is a FragmentActivity from Fragment. I have tryed like this but FragmentActivity is not an activity so not works. Thanks!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FichaFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sorry, was my issue, I have no declared the ActionBarActivity in the manifest